# R: Displaying ARIMA forecast as extension of past data after log transformation

Tags: r, plot, time-series, forecasting, arima

My goal: I want to understand a time series, a strongly auto-regressive one (ACF and PACF output told me that) and make a forecast.

So what I did was I first transformed my data into a ts, then decomposed the time series, checked its stationarity (the series wasn't stationary). Then I conducted a log transformation and found an Arima model that fits the data best - I checked the accuracy with accuracy(x) - I selected the model with the accuracy output closest to 0.

Was this the correct procedure? I'm new to statistics and R and would appreciate some criticism if that wasn't correct.

When building the Arima model I used the following code:

```
ARIMA <- Arima(log(mydata2), order=c(2,1,2), list(order=c(0,1,1), period=12))
```

The result I received was a log function and the data from the past (the data I used to build the model) wasn't displayed in the diagram. So then to transform the log into the original scale I used the following code:

```
ARIMA_FORECAST <- forecast(ARIMA, h=24, lambda=0)
```

Is that correct? I found it somewhere on the web and don't really understand it.

Now my main question: How can I plot the original data and the ARIMA_FORECAST in one diagram? I mean displaying it the way the forecasts are displayed if no log transformation is undertaken - the forecast should be displayed as the extension of the data from the past, confidence intervals should be there too.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to set the Box-Cox transformation parameter $\lambda=0$ within the modelling function, rather than take explicit logarithms (see https://otexts.org/fpp2/transformations.html). Then the transformation will be automatically reversed when the forecasts are produced. This is simpler than the approach described by @markus. For example:

```
library(forecast)

# estimate an ARIMA model to log data
ARIMA <- auto.arima(AirPassengers, lambda=0)

# make a forecast 
ARIMA_forecast <- forecast(ARIMA)

# Plot forecasts and data
plot(ARIMA_forecast)
```

[image]

Or if you prefer ggplot graphics:

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(ARIMA_forecast)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you markus and Rob so much! I didn't know it could be simplified to that extent. But I'm happy that the result I received now using your method is very similar to what I received before when using the "manual" method of creating a log and then de-logging.

Comment: @RobHyndman I cannot believe someone voted my answer up but not yours. I hope by my (not so good) answer your answer will get more validity. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The package `forecast` provides the functions `autolayer` and `geom_forecast` that might help you to draw the desired plot. Here is an example using the `AirPassengers` data. I use the function `auto.arima` to estimate the model.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)

# log-transform data
dat <- log(AirPassengers)

# estimate an ARIMA model
ARIMA <- auto.arima(dat)

# make a forecast 
ARIMA_forecast <- forecast(ARIMA, h = 24, lambda = 0)
```

Since your data is of class `ts` you can use the `autoplot` function from `ggplot2` to plot your original data and add the forecast with the `autolayer` function from `forecast`.

```
autoplot(AirPassengers) + forecast::autolayer(ARIMA_forecast)
```

The result is shown below.

[image]